# Как добавить к float числу символ $

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть файл pricebitcoin.py

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time


class Currency:
    url = 'юрл'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'юзер агент'}
    diferent = 1
    compare_currency = 0

 # init
    def __init__(self):
        self.compare_currency = float(self.get_currency())

# get currency bitcoin
    def get_currency(self):
        full_page = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
        convert = soup.findAll(
            "span", {"class": "DFlfde SwHCTb"})
        priceformat = (convert[0].text).replace(",", "")
        return priceformat
```

который выводит цену биткоина.
Также есть файл bot.py

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import config
import pricebitcoin

curen = pricebitcoin.Currency()


# Объект бота
bot = Bot(config.token)
# Диспетчер для бота
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


# Хэндлер на команду /price
@dp.message_handler(commands="price")
async def priceb(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(curen.get_currency())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Запуск бота
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

через который запускается объект из файла pricebitcoin.py, а также выводит цену по команде /price.
Но он выводит цену в типе float без символа $. Я уже пытался как-то его добавить, но ничего не получилось

Comment: Ну так преобразуйте float в str и допишите к ней всё что требуется. `await message.answer(f"${curen.get_currency()}")`

Comment: спасибо всё получилось